# Podcast syncing problem after switching .live.co.uk accounts

Tags: zune, sync, podcast

Podcasts were syncing fine between Zune and phone until yesterday, but now won't sync automatically at all.

The problem began when I switched to a second live.co.uk account on the desktop.

I've tried signing in and out and in again with both accounts and there's definitely no podcast syncing on either account. So I don't know if the switching between accounts is significant.

**What I've tried**
There's lots of advice online for this, so plenty of things to try. NOne of them have worked for me so far. I've tried:

- restarting everything
- resubscribing to selected podcast feeds, deleting, recreating and dragging the feed to the phone
- checked that zune is set to "sync all podcasts", not just the "items I choose"/"manually"
- using a different USB port - no difference
- using "forget this phone" link and reconnecting which gives the phone a new identity, then ensuring all feeds go to the "new" device
- deleting the RSA Crypto type folder as suggested [here](http://www.governor.co.uk/news-plus-views/2011/3/29/zune-can%27t-connect-to-your-phone-disconnect-it,-restart-it,-then-try-connecting-again)
- creating a new certificate via certmgr as suggested [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468307)

AS I say, none of these have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it, and I'll post the answer here but it's probably unusual to run into this problem (of multiple @live accounts) so I don't know how useful it'll be.

I *think* the problem was that the phone was associated with a newer @live account and on the zune/desktop my default account (and all podcasts) were setup with an older @live account. It seems as if this wasn't a problem at all.

Except and until. Except and until I signed in with the newer @live account on the desktop/zune. At that point, it seems, the desktop and the phone realised they were now properly on the same @live account and while I *could* go back to the old account in the zune software (and still download new episodes), that account's ability to sync podcasts with the phone was gone forever.

The solution was to erase the old account in the zune desktop software and setup all the podcasts in the new account. I did this manually which was a bore with 30+ podcasts but at least it's working now.